# Flipping a view that is contained on a view setup

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios5

I currently have a xib that is a standard view that has another view contained on top.  I want the user to be able to click on this subview, and then have this subview flip over when pressed.  I currently have code that flips the view around, but since I'm not explicitly assigning a new view, it just flips over and displays the same view.  Here is my code when the button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)flipCard:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Subview button was clicked!");

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
               forView:self.frontOfView
                 cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The biggest question is how to set this up.  Do I need to create an entire view programmatically and then just call `[[self view] addSubview: backOfView]*`?  Or is there a way to do this with interface builder?

*Note I haven't actually create a "backOfView" object, I'm not sure how I should create one at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one?

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.frontOfView
                    toView:self.backOfView
                  duration:0.4f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: Well, the thing is, I don't have a "backOfView" it was there for demonstration purposes, I will update that.  The question was, how "should I" create "backOfView?"  As it's own xib? Or programmatically?

Comment: You can either create it with xib or programmatically. You can just add code `UIViewController * backOfViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,300)] autorelease]` above the code I gave, and then replace `toView:self.backOfView` to `backOfViewController.view`. Hope it works what you want. :)